# Javascript Count number of time same value repeated in the textbox(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code add as yes if the master class text box value matches with the user but i want to compare the master with the user class and print the number count result in a div of how many input user class have the same repeated value of as master has.

Html:

```
<input class="master" value="1">
<input class="user" value="1">
<input class="user" value="1">
<input class="user" value="0">
<input class="user" value="0">
                    <div id="result_count"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var master = $('input.master').get(0).value; // get the master value
  var fn = function() {
    return this.value === master ? "yes" : "no";//if current text-box matches master,then yes else no
  };
  $('input.user').val(fn); // loop and replace text for each user input
});
```

Comment: What is the input `type`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 it is all text

Comment: @Shaik check my answer it will ouput 2 because 2 input with class user has same value with master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the attribute selector based on the master input's value:

```
$(function() {
  var master = $('input.master').val(); // get the master value
  var userInputs = $('input.user');

  var fn = function() {
    return this.value === master ? "yes" : "no";//if current text-box matches master,then yes else no
  };

  userInputs.val(fn); // loop and replace text for each user input

  // get inputs who has the same value as "master"
  var inputs = userInputs.filter( 'input[value="'+ master +'"]' )

  // Print the number of matches 
  console.log( inputs.length )
});
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/gjangztm/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/qOqKJe?editors=101

```
var masterValue = $('.master').val();
var $userInputs = $('.user');
var resultCount = $userInputs.filter(function(i, input) {
  return $(input).val() === masterValue;
});

$('#result_count').text(resultCount.length);
```

Comment: i need the count no of user class who has the same value as the master the above nothing shows up

Comment: I fixed the entry and added an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var same = $('input.user').filter(function( index ) {
    return ($(this).val() == $('.master').val());
  })
console.log(same.length);
$('#result_count').text(same.length);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6d39f10/1/)

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for more information

Comment: The filtering is not that complex, and as far as readability goes, it is a lot more clearer for beginners to use the attribute selector..

Comment: @elad.chen actually i just followed the documentation. I am a beginner as well and i was able to understand how it works just by reading the documentation.Because this is exactly like what the example in the documentation is

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
var count=0;
  var master = $('input.master').get(0).value; // get the master value
  var fn = function() {
    return this.value === master ? "yes" : "no";//if current text-box matches master,then yes else no
  };
  $('input.user').val(fn);

  $(".user").each(function() {
   if($(this).val()==master ){
    ++count;
     }
   });
 $('#result_count').val(count);
});
```